# Would it be possible to close questions because of insufficient research effort?

Tags: discussion

On serverfault it is possible to close questions due to insufficient research:

> Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations
>   are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam
>   answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe
>   the business problem you are working on, the research you have done,
>   and the steps taken so far to solve it.

According to me the following questions should be closed as there was insufficient research before asking the question:

1. [Kibana splitting up hostname as multiple fields in graphs](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/kibana-splitting-up-hostname-as-multiple-fields-in-graphs)
2. [How to create hybrid docker swarm mode cluster with multi-os application deployment?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3336/210)
3. [How can I successfully debug a watcher? My watchers don't seem to do anything](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3516/210)
4. [Minikube - Is there a way to run Windows Containers?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3501/210)
5. [Logging ansible crons in kibana](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3500/210)
6. [Kibana is unable to sort on some numbers](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3497/210)
7. [What can explain ElasticSearch 2.4 not accepting to create watchers via curl?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3495/210)
8. [Making gitlab-ci not run the default scripts](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3022/210)
9. [Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin is slow to make slave nodes. How can I speed it up?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3171/210)
10. [Converting an fai-chboot to a dirinstall](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3193/210)
11. [CloudFormation deregister older batch job definition revision](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3280/210)
12. [Where can I find older versions of GitLab Runner?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/881/210)
13. [Microservices terminology i.e. distinguishing between "core " and "other service instances"](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3529/210)

Comment: Is the question about adding a third (and last) canned close reason or about topicness of this kind of questions?

Comment: yes about a third closed reason indeed

Comment: That's just 2 question, closing with a comment should works... I'm unsure of which way to go

Comment: I thought it would be could to align with Serverfault instead of just typing it over an over again, e.g. "I think this question should be closed because the question shows insufficient research attempts". Why not adding extra options? Ok, I will extend the list of questions that are possible candidates to be closed to this Q
&A.

Comment: We can have only 3 custom off topic reasons, so before adding the last one I wait for some more reasoning about what problem it aim to solve. Even more as some of your exemples don't have even 1 close vote and are up voted, that doesn't sound like those questions are not welcome from the community

Comment: Just forgot a point before, the tooltip on the downvote button says: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful", which boilds down to the point bad questions should be downvoted and not closed, the roomba will delete them: "The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions that have negative score that are at least 30 days old. (RemoveDeadQuestions)" (Taken from [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: Related if not duplicate: 
 [What is the best way to close a question that is fully answerable with a single google search?](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/13)

Answer (score 2):

I feel like closing a question because not enough research was done prior to asking is a bit against what SE is about.  Creating a reason for closing because not enough research was done, I feel, may allow for an elitist atmosphere to form.  When the community on SE is so young (as is devops) I feel as these questions are going to be common as people search for their issues and questions.  I feel that if these questions do arise and it is obvious that no research was done, I think it would be better for the community to answer the specific question being asked by linking and quoting the documentation where they could have found their answer.  This way future visitors who may experience the same thing can be helped, as is the purpose of this community.

I don't think we should be doing peoples work, but I do know that often, stack exchange sites are among the first results when searching for information or tutorials, examples etc.  I have seen questions from other SE that the community at the time was heckling the poster for his question, but has since become the top google result.

tl;dr;
IMO closing b/c user didn't research enough goes against the idea of this community. lets keep the questions open (including this one), answer them with quotes and links to the tutorial so that we can be that resource future visitors years to come.  "Give me teh codez" questions should be flagged and closed.  We are too small to close topics because not enough research was done.  IMO we are the research people look for, especially in a field as young as devops.

Comment: Ok. I am open for discussion, but what I learned from other StackExchange sites is that a minimal research should be done. What is your opinion about [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3661/210), [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3660/210) and [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3659/210) question? In my opinion we should prevent "throw it over the wall" questions.

Comment: @030 my opinion is follow the usual guide, downvote if there's not enough research

Comment: @030 It would seem as though this individual is having trouble grasping the concept of secret management with AWS.  If you have the guides handy, I would link the guides and parapharse the guide.  You could also ask the user for more information such as, what have you tried, have you looked at resource X.  Have them ask a more specific question. This may be this first persons time with cloud environments and is just asking for guidance as best as they can.  If you don't like the question you can down vote it.  I wouldn't close it unless it would provide no benefit in the future.